# Is it possible to make Blender remember the names of authors or tags and suggest them if you fill in the Asset Browser?

Tags: asset-browser

I'm looking for a way to store the authors / tags I'm using when I fill up those fields in the Asset Browser. It really takes a lot of time to type in the same name or put the same tag.

It would be much easier to choose from a list, for example.

Is there a script I can use? ... something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not really an answer to your problem but you can check out my addon that has features to batch-assign authors, tags and descriptions to assets. https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities/releases your need seems like a QOL feature that will be implemented natively in the future. I've added an entry to see if I can add a feature in my addon regarding this need which is reasonable. https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities/issues/105

Comment: Wow! Thank you,Gorgious56! I've asked for a cookie and I get a full cake. :) Great job!